# Can Lightroom CC be sandboxed (Mac)?

Tags: lightroom, macintosh, os-x

I really hate what Adobe does to my computer, putting files in many places, and I would really like to have a sandbox version of Lightroom, like the one that sold in the App store before Lightroom 5 released.

Is it possible to manually sandbox Lightroom 5.x (with creative cloud support)?

Comment: "putting files in many places" Do you mean the app's files, or photos?

Comment: You mention Lightroom CC and Lightroom 5.x. I thought there was only 5.x; the desktop version. The CC package includes that same desktop version along with the web and mobile versions, too. Perhaps a small point, but clarity is always good.

Comment: The uninstallation procedure for LR on OS X is [drag app to trash, then delete the prefs file](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/manually-remove-lightroom.html#main_Remove_Lightroom_on_Mac_OS). That hardly counts as "files in many places."

Comment: @WarrenYoung, Thanks. I have that bad experience from other Adobe applications (e.g. Acrobat Reader, Flash and Revel). That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, by hand, redirect the various files the native Lr application creates and reads at runtime once installed (and run once). About the only thing you can't, as far as I know, is the platform specific settings properties, which end up where ever the OS says a particular login preferences should go.

But the raw cache, photos, catalogues, plugins (though, again, these are assumed to be in your user "Documents" directory now, I recall), etc. can all be set to specific locations.

This is the nature of native apps; most users want the app to feel "native" and not like a port or a web app. Therefore, following the platform specific recommendations for app defaults and letting the user change where user data goes (with recommendations) has been the gold standard for years.

I know of no way to "sandbox" the native app to a single file system area as one can a web app.